# How do I remove [" "] from json output?

Tags: jquery, json

I've got this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#inverter_err').change(function() {   
    var qString = 'err=' +$(this).val();
    $.post('err_query.php', qString, processResponse);
});

function processResponse(data) {
    if(data != "false") {
        $("#result").html(data).show("slow");
    }
    else {
        $("#result").hide("slow");
    }
}
});
```

When there's a positive result from the err_query.php (which is a simple sql query resulting in a `echo json_encode($array);)`, the result comes as a `["The result"]`.
How do I remove the `["  "]` ? I just need to display the text.

Comment: Shouldn't you (or jQuery) be _parsing_ the JSON response?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a newbie at jQuery. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: What @MattBall is saying - is that that is how JSON is supposed to be outputted, regardless of language (JavaScript or otherwise) - with double quotes for both keys and values. To parse through it - you should refer jquery's docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: And to be clear, the sample you've provided is a an array with one string in it. `[]` represents an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's returning a JSON array, so:

```
var value = JSON.parse(data)[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the response. Try this:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Or if you want to use jQuery:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: jQuery should parse the response automatically if PHP sends the right `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Or if you supply the right dataType. `$.post(url,data,handler,"json")`

Comment: If I use $.post(url,data,handler,"json") I only get a blank div. I've also tried mattytommo's suggestion, and here I also get a blank div.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the follow line:

```
$.post('err_query.php', qString, processResponse);
```

To

```
$.post('err_query.php', qString, processResponse, 'json');
```

Which indicate that the type of data expected from the server is JSON.

Comment: Default is "Intelligent Guess", which is based on response. If server response is plain text, JSON will not parse correctly the data.

Comment: Well actually var value = JSON.parse(data)[0]; did the trick.